# Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection when running SDMtune::train(method = Maxent, data = data, folds = folds) in R

Tags: r, temporary-files, rjava

i am trying to run a MaxEnt model using SDMtune::train function, but I keep receiving an error that I haven't been able to fix (code down below). The weird thing is that I have been able to run this code earlier (e.g. last week) without errors, and I don't understand what has changed since. All objects that are used in the model seem to be fine. I have tried to reinstall rJava, SDMtune as well as R and Rstudio.

```
hmo_default_model_cv_auc <- train(method = "Maxent", data = hmo_train, folds = hmo_folds_cb)
```

**Result**:

> Loading required namespace: rJava

> Error: Error reading files
> Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In file(con, "r") :
> cannot open file 'C:\Users\koivusus\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGKclEu\file5e82da63d2e/species.lambdas': No such file or directory

Comment: Similarly @Adriaan, please check to make sure the tags are applicable. In this case, the [tag:rstudio] tag explicitly says *"DO NOT use this tag for general R programming problems"*, since that tag is about the IDE itself. That tag is applicable when the question does not work in `Rterm` or when the code produces different results in R (inside RStudio) and R (not in RStudio); I don't think this question reflects that.